# i installed pipwin but cant install pyaudio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, installation, pip, pyaudio

pipwin install PyAudio
pipwin : The term 'pipwin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- pipwin install PyAudio
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pipwin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Where did you install it?  On Windows, `pip` usually goes into the Python "Scripts" directory.  That has to be on your PATH to be found.

Comment: I am using windows, how can i corect the PATH

Comment: `dir /s \users\matija\appdata\pipwin.exe` should find it, if that's where your Python is installed.

Answer (score 0):

This error `(ObjectNotFound: (pipwin:String))` is telling you that pipwin can't be found which means that you either installed it in the wrong place or you didn't install it. To install pipwin you can go to the directory that you have your script in and type cmd in the title bar, like up [here (This is an image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOd0P.png). Then you can type `pip install pipwin`. Or you can type it in the terminal of the IDE that your using.

Comment: if its in the wrong place how could i fix that

Comment: Idk, if you can run `pip show pipwin` then you shouldn't get this error`(ObjectNotFound: (pipwin: String))` when you run `pipwin install pyaudio` and you should be able to not get an error when you run `pipwin` in the terminal

Comment: mybe it is in the wrong place or similar

Comment: @Kova Try to type `pip install pipwin` in the terminal(If on VSCode you can press ctrl+j to open it) and then try running `pipwin install pyaudio` and tell me what is the output you get

Comment: all the requerments are satisfied but 'pipwin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.'

Comment: Sorry for answering very late. But did you run `pip install pipwin` before you ran `pipwin install pyaudio`?

Comment: yes i did,should i mybe change the python version to 3.6

Comment: maybe. Can you send what output you get when you write `pip install pipwin`?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pipwin in c:\users\matija\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (0.5.1)          its like this for every file

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to execute `pip install pipwin` again? It looks like you have not installed it or you have not installed it in the environment you have selected.

If it works, could you execute `pip show pipwin` and `get-command pipwin`(PowerShell) or `where pipwin`(CMD)?

Comment: pip show pipwin works but get-command pipwin and where pipwin dont work

Comment: what's the location of `pipwin`, and which python interpreter you have selected?

Comment: I am using Vs code and the location is c:\users\matija\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages